# Implementing sub-objects of the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

My question is pretty general in principle. I have a class called `Menu` that has a list of `items` and one or more of those items can be either a string, or another instance of `Menu`. My code for that looks like this:

```
class Menu():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    def add_item(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
    def add_menu(self):
        self.add_item(Menu())
```

As you can see I've used the actual name of the class `Menu` within one of it's functions. My question is if it's possible to do that without writing the actual name of the class, but rather by referring to what class it's defined in? For example, I've tried

```
self.add_item(super(self))
```

Which gives `TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not Menu` and also tried

```
self.add_item(super())
```

That runs without error, but the object it inserts is `<super: <class 'Menu'>, <Menu object>>`

I'm beginning to suspect i'm using the wrong tool for the job, and my question is what i'm doing wrong? and is referencing of the type I require even possible?

If it's relevant my python version is 3.5.3

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is possible:

```
>>> class A:
...     def create_instance(self):
...         return type(self)()
...
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = a1.add_self()
>>> a1
<__main__.A object at 0x1029c27f0>
>>> a2
<__main__.A object at 0x1029c28d0>
```

Note, of course, this is because:

```
>>> type(a1)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> A
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> type(a1) is A
True
```

Alternatively, this may also be a use-case for `classmethod`:

```
>>> class A:
...     @classmethod
...     def make_instance(cls):
...         return cls()
...
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = a1.make_instance()
>>> a1
<__main__.A object at 0x1029c29b0>
>>> a2
<__main__.A object at 0x1029c27f0>
```

Now, it is perfectly reasonable for instances of a class to return new instances of the same class, but whether or not it is advisable in your case I don't think I have enough information to give an opinion. But it is certainly possible.

Comment: My god, as simple as `type(self)()`? Seems so obvious a thing to miss.... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong abstraction: consider creating a class **MenuItem** for example - that represents single line menu entries, or sub menus. Or some *other* kind of menu entry that you can't think of today.

In other words: good OOP is about creating helpful *abstractions*. Menu items can have many different shapes, thus the better answer is not to fit in raw strings, but think up an inheritance hierarchy that supports you solving your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I fail to see how this helps me. The `items` in the question can be anything at all, nothing limits an item from being a `dict` or a `list`, but I do want to have the option of an item being of the same class as it's "parent"